# Slideshow and video application

Tags: software-recommendation, video

I am looking for a way that I can place a handful of mixed images (JPG) and videos (AVI?, MP4?) in a directory and loop through them continuously, in full screen, creating a slideshow from the images and playing the videos.  I do require the ability to add and remove files from that directory, and have the outputting show reflecting the changes.  Transition effects would be nice, but are not required.  A little bit of Bash or Python scripting would be fine, but I would like to avoid a full custom software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VLC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/) does that. You can open a directory as media source through *Media* > *Open Directory*, all items in there will show up under the *My Computer* item. Select them all and click play; by default pictures are shown for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

For the images, you can try [PixTeller](https://pixteller.com/create/slideshow) and create a slideshow