# Is there an image and video viewer like on smart phones in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player, image-viewers

I would like to present images and videos from one folder in Ubuntu just the way one is familiar with from smart phones/tablets.

Perfect would be if the The GNOME image viewer would be able to include videos with the most common formats with a still image into its preview/slideshow and would play them with a button-hit or mouse click. So the idea is to have images and videos in the same slideshow/fullscreen-view as in Android or iOS MediaViewers.

I found [Slideshow and video application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417780/slideshow-and-video-application) but this predetermines the duration a image is shown. I would like to present the next image/video in the folder manually (also in fullscreen) and would like to start video-playback manually as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can use gThumb. gThumb can view images and play videos directly.

Install it with the command

```
sudo apt install gthumb
```

Take a look at its project page https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb

Comment: thanks for the hint, I checked it out but gthumb seems to:
- omit videos in slideshows
- draw a border around images/videos in fullscreen mode that I can't configure and seems to autostart videos in fullscreen (instead of manual starting videos) with not shortcut to play/pause videos

Comment: Well, slideshows are for images only. No? I think you're looking for solutions that can preview images and vidoes.

Comment: Slideshow in this case might be misleading that's why I added the analogy with the smart device usecase. But gThumb is a good move forward compared with the gnome image viewer, as it includes videos at least.

Comment: @soriak That is the closest I could get.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using VLC. You can find it in the repositories. You can add Images using the menu entry: Media -> Open Multiple Files.

You can use shortcuts to play the next item (video or image): CTRL + Right Arrow.

You can change the duration of an image being shown following the instructions that you can find here: https://www.vlchelp.com/image-slideshow-photo-view/